# How to add virtual hosts without having to restart apache?

Tags: apache-2.2

When I read tutorial on how to create /add virtual hosts, the last sentence is always something like:

> ... now restart apache and you are done!

Now, many (most|all) web hosts have a panel that allow you to create new virtual hosts which are activated almost instantly... and I am sure they didn't restart apache (inconveniencing hundreds of other users) just for my pleasure!

So how to change apache settings / adding virtual hosts, etc. and reloading the new settings without actually restarting the apache server?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
$ /etc/init.d/httpd reload
```

This will run a config syntax check and then will make apache reload its config files without interrupting traffic.

Comment: Oh, cool! I new about the start|stop|restart options, but not about the reload one. Thanks.

Comment: Some change also requires `force-reload` rather than `reload`.

Comment: and make sure you do a:

service httpd configtest

before your reload - it won't get all config errors, but it catches some.

Comment: @Jason, at least on Debian/Ubuntu, the above command runs a config test (and ensures that it exits cleanly) before issuing the `apache2ctl graceful`.

Answer (score 10):

Most linux distros have a small utility called apachectl or apache2ctl, which you can use to just reload the configuration. This will also activate any new virtual hosts.
The command you are looking for is
`apache2ctl graceful`

Comment: Thanks. I'll certainly check them out. How does this compare to the other solution: <code>$ /etc/init.d/httpd reload </code>

Comment: @augustin: the init script is a wrapper around `apache2ctl`. I would rather use the init script because it might also launch apache2 as a specific user, which you'd have to know in order to use `apache2ctl`. Trust in the tools that come with your distribution :-)